# CH340 ESP-01 programmer

Tags: drivers, usb, hardware

I have [this programmer](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-ESP01-Programmer-Adapter-UART-GPIO0-ESP-01-Adaptateur-ESP8266-USB-NEW-/222121082897) for an [ESP-01 chip](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP8266-Esp-01-Serial-Port-WIFI-Transceiver-WIFI-Wireless-Chip-Module-AP-STA-/131407358986) and it should be fairly straightforward using this. 
My problem is that my Linux Mint 18 does not give any sign that the chip is plugged in, zero.

I have tried `lsusb` and it shows no news, `dmesg` shows no news. The drivers should be included, I found this.

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic/include/config/usb/serial/ch341.h
```

I have already replaced the ESP-01 and the programmer. What would be a good next step?

*Feel free to vote this question down but please do comment what I should improve on.

**[EDIT]**

When I used the one single port that this USB adapter works on, the DMESG looks like this:

```
usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-11: Product: USB2.0-Serial
ch341 3-11:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
usb 3-11: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

And now hen I ask for the chip_id:

```
sudo ./esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 chip_id
```

Then  the result from [esptool](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) is this:

```
Connecting...
Chip ID: 0x0013b6e3
```

[image: ESP-01]
[image: programmer]

Comment: Can `avrdude` or the Arduino software find it? I've had some programmers (e.g. the `usbtiny` that do not appear as USB devices, but can still be programmed with the beforesaid.)

Comment: no it does not, I also use a programmer for ATMEGA328 and then it's found with avrdude like you say.

Comment: Does the red led light up, and the blue led flash as described [here](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=getting-started-with-the-esp8266)?

Comment: yes and it starts as AP with SSID something with AITINKER so it looks powered fine

Comment: Also try plugging the usb device directly on the computer port, not via cable (some can have no data wires!), not via a hub (some are fussy).

Comment: It indeed looks like a port problem, have 12 USB ports or so and the thing only works on one single port.